# Estilos no se aplican al placeholder de varios inputs

Tags: html, css

Me encuentro haciendo el diseño de unos input y textarea para mi pagina.
En el CSS cuando intento cambiar el color de lo que aparece en el placeholder, el css no me lo toma, yo creo que lo estoy haciendo de la forma correcta. Este es el codigo:

```
    input::placeholder{
      color:white;
    }
```

El codigo HTML:

```
 <div class="col-xs-12">
  <input class="form-control formulario" type="" name="name" placeholder="Nombre">
  <input class="form-control formulario" type="" name="name" placeholder="Email">
  <textarea placeholder="Escribe tu mensaje aquí"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola @BetaM. Tengo dos archivos CSS. El styles.css que es donde trabajo y el archivo de bootstrap4

Comment: Si, lo tengo tal cual @BetaM. Primero tengo el link del bootstrap y despues el link de style.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema de que tu regla no se aplique proviene de la especificidad del selector que estás escribiendo, es decir:

Al momento solo estás cubriendo:

- Selector de tipo
- Selector de pseudoelementos

Que se consideran los de menor especificidad

Deberías tener en cambio un selector así:

```
.formulario::placeholder{
    color:white;
}
```

Para que de este modo:

- Uses el selector de clase
- Selector de pseudoelementos

Los selectores de clase son mas específicos que los de tipo y/o los de pseudoelemento

**Lecturas de interés**

- [Pseudoelemento ::placeholder](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/::placeholder)
- [Especificidad CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Especificidad)
- [Selectores CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Selectores_CSS)

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, me funciono! voy a leer las lecturas que me dejaste para que no me vuelva a pasar.

Answer (score 0):

Allí deberías estar haciendo referencia de forma más especifica a una clase más que a un elemento, en tu caso no sería el  `input::placeholder{`.... Sino  a la clase, que sería: `.input::placeholder{`

Sino se te hace el cambio es porque ya tienes otra clase que esta afectando a placeholder y le esta dando prioridad.

En CSS tienes varias formás para hacer referencia a cambios de varias etiquetas `.input` es una clase  `input` solo sería los selectores y `#input` hace referencia a un ID.

Comment: No, pero el en su html puede dentro de la etiqueta que quiere hacer el cambio llamar a esa clase y listo, super sencillo

Comment: Él amigo hizo referencia al archivo css cierto? le aclaré la duda desde mi punto de vista